# Booting 19.04 from LUKS system drive

Tags: grub2, encryption, luks, 19.04

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 19.04 on an encrypted system drive with LUKS. The installation finishes, but GRUB doesn't ask for a password and the system won't boot.

I've found a few other questions about this, but they result in dead links or tell me to set `CRYPTFS=y` and run `update-initramfs`. I think this is already the default in Ubuntu 19.04, but I tried it anyway and it doesn't work.

How can I make GRUB ask for a password on boot?

## Summary

1. Disks:

   - `/dev/sda1`: `/boot/efi`, unencrypted
   - `/dev/sda2`: `/boot`, unencrypted
   - `/dev/sda3`, `/dev/mapper/cryptroot`: `/`, encrypted
2. Installed Kubuntu using the mount points above
3. Added `cryptdevice=UUID=6d5b5f47-58e8-4a9c-89c8-4f503f35ff3f:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot` to `/etc/default/grub` and ran `update-grub` in chroot
4. I see GRUB, I see the Kubuntu splash screen and then just a blinking underscore

## Details

1. Boot from live CD
2. Partition disk using `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

   - `/dev/sda1`: EFI System
   - `/dev/sda2`: Linux filesystem
   - `/dev/sda3`: Linux filesystem

   ```
   Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
   Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
   Be careful before using the write command.

   Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
   Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x087d3a28.

   Command (m for help): g
   Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: 73F157B8-7425-7844-AE8E-3A46EF2ED5A4).

   Command (m for help): n
   Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
   First sector (2048-20971486, default 2048): 
   Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-20971486, default        20971486): +128M

   Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 128 MiB.

   Command (m for help): t
   Selected partition 1
   Partition type (type L to list all types): 1
   Changed type of partition 'Linux filesystem' to 'EFI System'.

   Command (m for help): n
   Partition number (2-128, default 2): 
   First sector (264192-20971486, default 264192): 
   Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (264192-20971486, default        20971486): +512M

   Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 512 MiB.

   Command (m for help): n
   Partition number (3-128, default 3): 
   First sector (1312768-20971486, default 1312768): 
   Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (1312768-20971486, default        20971486): 

   Created a new partition 3 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 9.4 GiB.

   Command (m for help): w

   The partition table has been altered.
   Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
   Syncing disks.
   ```
3. Encrypt root partition using `sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sda3`
4. Mount the encrypted drive using `sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 cryptroot`
5. Format the partitions:

   1. EFI partition: `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1`
   2. Boot partition: `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2`
   3. Root partition: `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/cryptroot`
6. Install Kubuntu using these devices (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/mapper/cryptroot`)
7. Chroot into the installed Kubuntu:

   1. Mount required devices:

      ```
      sudo mount /dev/mapper/cryptroot /mnt
      sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
      sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
      sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
      sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
      ```
   2. Enter chroot: `sudo chroot /mnt`
   3. Adjust kernel parameters (`/etc/default/grub`):

      ```
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=6d5b5f47-58e8-4a9c-89c8-4f503f35ff3f:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot"
      ```

      I've also tried:

      ```
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.luks.name=6d5b5f47-58e8-4a9c-89c8-4f503f35ff3f=cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot"
      ```
   4. Run `update-grub`
   5. **Missing step here (see answer)**
8. Reboot, when I boot without `quiet` I see the following output:

   ```
   [some other output]

   Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
   Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
   Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
   Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
   Begin: Waiting for root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
   done.
   Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
    - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
      - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
   ALERT!  /dev/mapper/cryptroot does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!

   [BusyBox shell]
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I was just missing one single step, which I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345898/set-initramfs-to-prompt-for-luks-passowrd-on-startup-on-mint-18).

Basically, while in chroot, I had to create `/etc/crypttab` with the following contents:

```
cryptroot UUID=6d5b5f47-58e8-4a9c-89c8-4f503f35ff3f none luks
```

And then run `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Comment: Why must you embed the UUID of the underlying crypt device if you're passing it on the GRUB cmdline?  if update-initramfs needs that just to turn on encryption, there must be another way.  Otherwise, if you make multiple thumb drives, the process becomes more involved.  (I only ask because I have multiple thumbdrives with the same image on them and want to figure out if I should configure it via the LUKS GRUB module or the initramfs).

Comment: I just inspected update-initramfs, I see no references to luks / crypt (how would it know to look at /etc/crypttab).  Perhaps all that is needed is the cryptroot option?  I disassembled an initramfs before and saw cryptops in the init script, but passing that didn't work.  Maybe the cryptroot above is the right one.

Comment: I suspect the answer might be in /usr/share/initramfs-tools.